# How to: When a bp Group created, automatically create a wp category

Tags: buddypress

example:
a user creates a group "cats"
automatically
a category "cats"  would be created
with the slug "cats"
or
a user creates a group "Fat Cats"
automatically
a category "Fat Cats"  would be created
with the slug fat-cats.
I see there is a function wp_create_category :
However,to be frank, i'm lost.

Have tried, with adding this near end (line310) of child-theme/groups/create.php
    
but no dice

Any help or ideas really welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an action where you can hook in. It is called: 'groups_created_group'. My idea is, that you hook into that and select the last group that was created. In database groups have a field called 'date_created'. So just read the name of the last one and create your group out of that.

You have to write this in your functions.php file of your theme:

```
function createCatAfterGroup() {
  global $wpdb;
  $group = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM `wp_bp_groups` ORDER BY date_created DESC");
  wp_insert_term($group->name, 'category');
}
add_action('groups_created_group', 'createCatAfterGroup');
```

Comment: thanks BUT tested and creating group stops at first template i.e Clicking Create Group and continue brings up blank screen what about using bp_get_new_group_name(); I see that in bp-groups-template.php . Your idea though is fantastic outside the box thinking! could you tweak it a little! i can try things but not fully sure what i'm doing!

Comment: No error? Take a look in your database, maybe the table has a different name. Can't be a big problem. In my mind it should work. :)

Comment: I got it working, i updated my post above with the correct code. You need to use wp_insert_term() instead.

Comment: bp_get_new_group_name() seems to give you the group you created before the one you actually want to have. Don't really know why.

Comment: tried again. the group 'movsky' IS being created and recorded in the database wp_bp_groups. The category is NOT being produced in wp_terms and clicking Create group and continue brings the white wall of death! pity, something tiny is holding it up!

Comment: That's strange. Are you sure it is the function what makes the white screen? It works perfectly here and also creates the category in wp_terms and wp_term_taxonomy. Did you undo your own tries in the group-core?

Comment: with the new code - wp_insert_term($group->name, 'category'); no longer the white screen   but no category is turning up

Comment: when i put this on a page nothing turns up    <?php
global $wpdb;
$group = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM 'wp_bp_groups' ORDER BY date_created DESC");
echo $group;
?>

Comment: Try to take a look if the data is in $group. Make a print_r($group); die(); after the database-select. If it is empty probably your tablenames are different.

Comment: group is an object, you should get a warning if you try to output it with echo. (Seems they are disabled on your server) try with print_r($group); instead.

Comment: no dice. Many Thanks for staying with this. doing this on a local install but its multisite/multi-network. will try it out on a basic buddypress install with no other distractions.

Comment: ok basic single site install bp default theme added function at end of functions.php. created group successfully. no new category created ???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6650/discussion-between-valentine-cosgrave-and-movsky)

Comment: TWould like to  adapt the excellent function provided by movsky in order that the category is created in another blog, not the blog in which buddypress is installed. Have tried the following but the outcome only gets some of the way

Comment: $wpdb->insert($blog_id, array ('term_id'=> NULL, 'name'=> $group, 'slug'=> $slug, 'term_group'=> '0'));
the name and slug are correctly entered into the appropriate wp_xx_terms table  but the it does not show up in the wordpress back-end. Any ideas at all really welcome.